# Is it possible to implement tostring string method and printf?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to Java.
My program is given an output in tabular form, and it returns from a method called **calculateShoes. I'm just wondering if it is possible to do printf while return is on there. I tried putting a System.out.printf (after the return statement) to use the "|%3d|" for spacing but it's not working.

`@Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return "|     " + this.numberOfShoes + "  |     " + this.sumOfShoesInputted 
      + "    |   " + this.lowestNumberOfShoes + " to " + this.highestNumberOfShoes + "|";
    }`

I realize that this looks messy, and the data outputted moves the "|". I would like to have it fixed and not resized all the time. I hope there's a cleaner way to do this.

**Sorry I had the wrong boolean method >_<.

Comment: print before returning

Comment: You shouldn't put anything after a return.

Comment: @C1pher - I realize that now haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
return String.format("|%3d|", some_variable);
```

This method works similarly to `System.out.printf()`

Comment: Wow that simple. Thanks, looks much cleaner :].